# How to correctly include webfonts into a bootstrap-sass project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass, webfonts, bootstrap-sass

I created a [bootstrap-sass project with yeoman generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-bootstrap-compass).

I want to add a webfont and everytime I compile my scss code I get the following error:

> error app/src/stylesheets/main.scss (Line 25: File not found or cannot
>   be read:
>   /Users/username/Desktop/testfolder/**fonts**/../fonts/nexa-webfont/nexaheavy-webfont.woff)

How can I get rid of the unnecessary
   ../testfolder/**fonts**/..     folder in the path?

My main.scss looks like this:

```
// VER: 0.1

/* OVERRIDDEN BOOTSTRAP VARIABLES */
$icon-font-path: "../fonts/bootstrap/";

/* STANDARD INCLUDES */
@import "bootstrap-compass";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "compass/css3";

/* CUSTOM FONT IMPORT */
@include font-face(
  "Nexa Heavy",
  inline-font-files(
    '../fonts/nexa-webfont/nexaheavy-webfont.woff', woff,
    '../fonts/nexa-webfont/nexaheavy-webfont.ttf', ttf,
    '../fonts/nexa-webfont/nexaheavy-webfont.svg', svg),
    '../fonts/nexa-webfont/nexaheavy-webfont.eot',
  normal, // font-weight
  normal  // font-style
);


/* CUSTOM INCLUDES */
@import "custom-variables";
@import "common";
@import "navigation";
@import "footer";

@import "pages/home";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we import fonts we use:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "diogenesregular";
  src: asset-url("assets/diogenes-webfont.eot");
  src: asset-url("assets/diogenes-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  asset-url("assets/diogenes-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
  asset-url("assets/diogenes-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
  asset-url("assets/diogenes-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
  asset-url("assets/diogenes-webfont.svg#diogenesregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Not quite sure about your setup or font kits though.
We place all our fonts in `app/assets/fonts` and import the fonts like above in `app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.scss` and then import this file in `application.scss`.

Comment: This works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can give you issues with precompiling :/

Comment: Can you post your current import block?